# Deploy multiple tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, deployment

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a database that includes 100 tables. 20 of them are my configurations. From time to time, I need updated our configuration and deploy these 20 tables to field (production, test etc). The other 80 tables need to be preserved. I looked at options such as bcp and SSIS. What is your suggestion or experience on this?

Comment: Script the changes to the config tables and leave the others alone.

Answer (score 0):

create script files with a 'truncate table tablename' as the first line, then a string of 'insert' statements to fill the table(s).  You could have all 20 table 'refreshes' in one file, or one table in each file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a database migration tool like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). Put every change to your database under revision control.

The following examples target  the [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database, but liquibase also [supports sql server](http://www.liquibase.org/databases.html). Liquibase is a java tool but can be used from the command-line on windows.

## Example (Manage Schema)

An [update](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/update.html) operation is executed as follows:

```
liquibase --url=jdbc:h2:db/scottTiger \
          --driver=org.h2.Driver \
          --username=user \
          --password=pass \
          --classpath=/path/to/db/jar/h2-1.3.172.jar \
          --changeLogFile=scottTiger.sql \
          update
```

This command will look at the changesets defined in a [specially formatted](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) sql file and only run changes that are missing.

This means the database can be updated in place (migration) or built from scratch.

### scottTiger.sql

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset mark:1
CREATE TABLE BONUS (ENAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, JOB VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, SAL DECIMAL(7, 2), COMM DECIMAL(7, 2));
ALTER TABLE BONUS ADD CONSTRAINT BONUS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ENAME, JOB);
--rollback DROP TABLE BONUS;

--changeset mark:2
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(14), LOCATION VARCHAR(13), CONSTRAINT DEPT_PK PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO));
--rollback DROP TABLE DEPARTMENT;


--changeset mark:3
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMPNO INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(10), JOB VARCHAR(9), BOSS INT, HIREDATE VARCHAR(12), SALARY DECIMAL(7, 2), COMM DECIMAL(7, 2), DEPTNO INT, CONSTRAINT EMP_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO));
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT BOSS_FK FOREIGN KEY (BOSS) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE (EMPNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES PUBLIC.DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
--rollback DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE;


--changeset mark:4
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (PROJECTNO INT NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100), START_DATE VARCHAR(12), END_DATE VARCHAR(12), CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PK PRIMARY KEY (PROJECTNO));
--rollback DROP TABLE PROJECT;

--changeset mark:5
CREATE TABLE ROLE (ROLE_ID INT NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100), CONSTRAINT ROLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_ID));
--rollback DROP TABLE ROLE;


--changeset mark:6
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_PARTICIPATION (PROJECTNO INT NOT NULL, EMPNO INT NOT NULL, START_DATE VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, END_DATE VARCHAR(12), ROLE_ID INT);
ALTER TABLE PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT PARTICIPATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PROJECTNO, EMPNO, START_DATE);
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMPNO) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE (EMPNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT PROJECT_FK FOREIGN KEY (PROJECTNO) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT (PROJECTNO) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PROJECT_PARTICIPATION ADD CONSTRAINT ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ROLE (ROLE_ID) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
--rollback DROP TABLE PROJECT_PARTICIPATION;

--changeset mark:7
CREATE TABLE SALARYGRADE (GRADE INT NOT NULL, LOSAL INT NOT NULL, HISAL INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT SALGRADE_PK PRIMARY KEY (GRADE));
--rollback DROP TABLE SALARYGRADE;
```

Notes:

- Each changeset has a unique name. Liquibase keeps a record of each changeset executed against your database instance
- Possible to define [rollback](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) actions. Very useful feature for undoing database changes.

## Example (Manage Data)

Liquibase has a useful [context feature](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) which can be leveraged to manage table data.

The following example specifies the "dev" context on the command-line:

```
liquibase --url=jdbc:h2:db/scottTiger \
          --driver=org.h2.Driver \
          --username=user \
          --password=pass \
          --classpath=/path/to/db/jar/h2-1.3.172.jar \
          --changeLogFile=scottTiger.sql \
          --contexts=dev
          update
```

### scottTiger.sql

Inside the changeset file the context is optionally indicated for each changeset. This enables liquibase to selectively run a particular changeset:

```
--changeset mark:8 context:dev
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (2,2,3);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (3,2,3);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (4,2,3);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (5,2,3);
--rollback DELETE FROM SALARYGRADE;

--changeset mark:9 context:test
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (1,20,30);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (2,20,30);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (3,20,30);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (4,20,30);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (5,20,30);
--rollback DELETE FROM SALARYGRADE;

--changeset mark:10 context:prod
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (1,200,300);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (2,200,300);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (3,200,300);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (4,200,300);
INSERT INTO SALARYGRADE (GRADE,LOSAL,HISAL) VALUES (5,200,300);
--rollback DELETE FROM SALARYGRADE;
```

Comment: Can you create multiple tables in one changeset?Tnx.

Comment: yes you can. I suppose that is only advised if both tables are functionally coupled, right?

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of users who use the [database change management features](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/features/all-features#database-management) in [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster) to manage a workflow you describe.

First and foremost, no matter what tool/technique you go with, you have to start with creating change scripts (SQL) that are to be run once (and only once). Changes that can be run multiple times (such as creating stored procs, views, etc), can be stored in source control and run every time deployment is done.

Once your application is configured in BuildMaster, you can set up multiple database connections (Test, Stage, Prod, etc), and automate the change delivery between environments. You can also generate a Deployment Tool (.exe) for use by developers or databases outside of your environments.

(disclaimer: I work for Inedo)